# "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file."Webpack, vue.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have a problem with images in Vue.js Webpack
My Vue.js template :

[image: <img :src="require('${elem.titleofgame.replace(/\s+/g, '')}')}.jpg) // its image url `]
(don't pay attention at red-line)

My package.json:

[image]

webpack.config.js:

[image]

and I am getting this error:

```
"Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)"
```

i tried  to add url-loader,  but its not working. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the rquire inside the img tag, if those images are local, just provide the path, relative to your current file, and the name of the image file. That should work.

Also do not use `url-loader` in these cases, url-loader converts images to base-64 if they are small enough, and that will not work for dynamic stuff most of the time.

You could also try importing all those local images, and then write some logic that will decide which image to to put in the src.

like:

```
import bike from '@/assets/images/bike.jpg'
//in the tempalte: 
<img :src="bike" />
```

This also works nicely, and it will not confuse vue-loader with dynamic imports in the template... if you have recent es features availabkle you could use dynamic import as well, but that depends on you and your code base...

Comment: Dynamic `src` URLs *do* need to be `require`d.

Comment: @tony19 I don't think so, url-s for sure do not need to be required or anything... for local images i am not 100% sure, but last time i tried it worked like a charm..., if you have an array of image url-s you can loop over them and just insert the url in the src and it will 100% work.

Comment: That would only work for literal URLs `<img src="@/assets/logo.png">`. But dynamic URLs that need `v-bind` (e.g., from string concatenation) must be `require`d.

Comment: Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/imgsrc-with-v-bind-needs-to-be-require-d-eg3nr?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: @tony19, i tried to do with require:` <img alt="Ahatintime" :src="require(`./assets/Ahatintime.jpg`)"   class="card-img-top" > ` , but i got this problem:` GET http://localhost:8080/[object%20Module] 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: I've not seen that problem before, as this isn't an issue in Vue CLI scaffolded projects. Try `:src="require('./assets/Ahatintime.jpg').default"`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that your are using Webpack dynamic import with fully dynamic argument. This is not allowed - see the documentation for [import()](https://v4.webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import) - same limitations described there applies also to a `require()` [where the argument is expression](https://v4.webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression) instead of simple static string